# Event occur after color detection

Tags: java, graphics, colors, awt

I want to know that can mouse click event detects colors or even strings.

For instance I have drawn yellow filled oval on screen and I want that if mouse clicked on that color, it will cause specific event to occur. Likewise I may have other different drawings on screen and i want different event occur for different colors.

Would it be possible in Java graphics?

Comment: for better help sooner edit quesstion with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Anything you can do in a component (e.g. draw colors & shapes, or detect click events) can be put into either an applet or a frame, so 'applet' becomes irrelevant (can also do it, but not needed) as a choice.  I removed applet from the text & tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as;

- Get screen coordinates of the click event
- Get the color of the screen at the given coordinates
- Then do your job according to the color

pseudo code:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{ 
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   Color clickedColor = robot.getPixelColor(e.getX(),e.getY());
   doSomething(clickedColor);
}
```

Detecting strings from an image is whole anoher subject. You need to search into "character/text recognition" in computer vision field. There are off the shelf libraries doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Robot.getPixelColor(x, y)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/):

> public Color getPixelColor(int x,
>                     int y)
>
> Returns the color of a pixel at the given screen coordinates.
>
> Parameters: x - X position of pixel
>
> y - Y position
>   of pixel
>
> Returns: Color of the pixel